# Axios React upload jpg

Tags: react-native, post, axios, multipart

I have photo file taken with ImagePicker, and I need upload it to server, using axios, and I need send type as a string with this photo.

My code here

```
const axiosMultipart = axios.create({
  timeout: 3000,
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
uploadDocs(token,type,photo){
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('photo', photo);
    data.append('type', type);

    return axiosMultipart
    .post(
      `uploadDocs`,
      {data},
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("uploadDocs: " + error));
  };
```

Server response is error_code 400
What is wrong here?
Also I have code on php with a working request
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With Below Code,

```
    var photo = {
        uri: file,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'photo.jpg',
    };


var FormData = require('form-data');
var form = new FormData();
form.append('photo', photo);
form.append('filetype', filetype);


axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        "Authorization": authData

    },
    data: form,
    url: `${base_url}`,
  
}).then(async (result) => {
    console.log("uploadFile detail Response===>", result);

   
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("uploadFile detail error===>", error);

    callback({ status: false, result: error })
});
```